# Extract multiline XML from log based on value in tag

Tags: regex, linux, xml, awk, grep

I have a log file on unix host (quite big one >500 MB) on daily basis with printed out XMLs there that are sent to other systems.

The XML structure is likely to the following one:

```
2021-01-04 08:44:43,174 Not related message
2021-01-04 08:45:45,174 [Sender] INFO  com....router.MessageRouter - Publishing Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Q1:book>
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
    <id>6AA2BC</id>
    <metadata>
       <isbn>123-432-234</isbn>
       <catalogId>111</catalogId>
    </metadata>
    <relatedBook>
       <metabook id="3AA345">Everyday Italian. Part 2</metabook>
       <metabook id="7ANNN2">Everyday Italian. Part 3</metabook>
    </relatedBook>
  </Q1:book>
2021-01-04 08:46:23,174 Not related message
2021-01-04 08:46:51,174 Not related message
2021-01-04 08:47:21,174 Not related message
2021-01-04 08:49:45,174 Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Q1:book>
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian. Part 2</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
    <id>3AA345</id>
    <metadata>
       <isbn>123-432-235</isbn>
       <catalogId>115</catalogId>
    </metadata>
    <relatedBook>
       <metabook id="6AA2BC">Everyday Italian. Part 2</metabook>
       <metabook id="7ANNN2">Everyday Italian. Part 3</metabook>
    </relatedBook>
  </Q1:book>
```

and there are dozens of XMLs in log like that.

I have id of the my desired xml (e.g. 6AA2BC) and I need to extract the full XML related to it using Linux commands.

if I do something like `grep 6AA2BC file.log` 
I will receive the only line `<id>3AA345</id>`

I have tried different approaches described by community and was able to get ALL XMLs using

`grep -Poz '(?<=<Q1:book)(.*?\n)*?.*?(?=</Q1:book>)' file.log`
but if I add id to the request, it does not work

The expected output: full XML with that particular id=6AA2BC

```
<Q1:book>
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
    <id>6AA2BC</id>
    <metadata>
       <isbn>123-432-234</isbn>
       <catalogId>111</catalogId>
    </metadata>
    <relatedBook>
       <metabook id="3AA345">Everyday Italian. Part 2</metabook>
       <metabook id="7ANNN2">Everyday Italian. Part 3</metabook>
    </relatedBook>
  </Q1:book>
```

Can anyone, please, explain what's the best way to do this?

Comment: You don't have to use grep but xml aware tools.

Comment: If you give a sample of an input file and the output you want, people will understand better your question.

Comment: There is an error in your input file: the `<isbn>` tag has no correspondig closing `</isbn>` tag. Please correct your question.

Comment: @PierreFrançois Updated. I can't publish the real log used in UAT, so I used this XML as a basis. I am limited to the commands in Linux. I saw 'sep' and 'awk' commands used widely for that but could not get the result due to quite complex syntax to me

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the input file `file.log` mixes the contents of several XML files and has several lines containing stuff as `2021-01-04 08:47:21,174 Not related message` into it. In that case, the xml aware tools (of Linux) will not work, since your input is not a well formed XML file.

Comment: It is a normal log containing XML in it as I mentioned before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper xml parser like xmlstarlet or xmllint is the best solution for XML but given there is none xml text in the file, awk is an alternative:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="(</Q1:book>)|(<Q1>)" } /<id>6AA2BC<\/id>/ { print "<Q1>";print $0;print "</Q1:book>" }' file
```

Set the record separator to "" or "</Q1:book>" and print the record along with the starting and ending Q1 tags when id is equal to 6AA2BC

Comment: I have updated it a bit for my purpose and provided XML.

awk 'BEGIN { RS="(</Q1:book>)|(<Q1:book)" } /<id>6AA2BC<\/id>/ {print "<Q1:book>";print $0;print "</Q1:book>

it returns XML with expected id. In my case, two of them as some modification was published

Thanks a lot. 
I need to read more about awk / sed

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for multi-char RS.

Comment: Output will be correct and look better with `awk 'BEGIN { RS="</Q1:book>|<Q1:book>" } /<id>6AA2BC<\/id>/ { print "  <Q1:book>" $0 "</Q1:book>" }' file.log`.

Answer (score 2):

Another one tested with GNU awk

```
awk '/<Q1/{f=1}f{i = i $0 ORS }/<\/Q1/{if(i~/<id>6AA2BC/){printf "%s", i} i=f="" }' file.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have the Perl script **xpath** installed on your Linux system, you could do the following:

To extract the node `Q1:book` having the text string `6AA2BC` in the subnode `id` from your input above, you could use:

```sh
/usr/bin/xpath -q -e '//Q1:book[id/text()="6AA2BC"]' file.log
```

But... first, you have to sanitize your input, and add a root opening tag in the beginning and the corresponding closing tag at the end.

As the XML lines begin with spaces, and the other lines without, keep the XML lines using the filter:

```sh
sed '/^[^ ]/d'
```

Add an opening root tag that must also include the definition of the `Q1` name space in order to work with the commands using XPATH selection:

```sh
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
echo '<root xmlns:Q1="https://example.com/mynamespace">'
```

in the beginning, and:

```sh
echo "</root>"
```

at the end.

Combining the above elements gives us the next one liner in Linux, that I will split on several lines for the sake of clarity

```sh
( echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
  echo '<root xmlns:Q1="https://example.com/mynamespace">'
  cat file.log | sed '/^[^ ]/d'
  echo "</root>"
) | /usr/bin/xpath -q -e '//Q1:book[id/text()="6AA2BC"]'
```

If you have **xmllint** on your system instead of **xpath**, just issue:

```sh
| /usr/bin/xmllint --xpath '//*[local-name()="book" and id/text()="6AA2BC"]' -
```

as last part of the command.

Comment: As I mentioned before, I need to do it using existing commands: grep, sep, awk, pcregrep installed by default
I can't install any tools to LInux, unfortunately(

Comment: Sorry, since **xpath** is a Linux command, I used it. I need to know if you have any XML aware commands installed on the host where you are working, like the Perl script **xpath** or **perl** itself, **xmllint**, **xmlstarlet**, etc...

Comment: perl and xmllint are there, but I can't save pl scripts there, so it should be something single line.

Comment: My solution also works with **xmllint**. I will edit my answer accordingly. If you can't accept it no more, at least you can upvote it.